# error when remove item from combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a piece of code, I can delete the first value but fails and give notice 
InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
     If ComboBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
         If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
             ComboBox1.Items.Remove(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
             'or
             'ComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
         End If
     End If
 End Sub
```

thank help !

Comment: can you edit your post and select the code then press Ctrl+K to format it please :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
If (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) // double equals to compare :-D
```

if the problem wasn't solved try this :

```
ComboBox1.Resources.Remove(ComboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will definitely solve your problem

```
ComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
```